Parsing this sentence with 目ぽかっと開けてるようになったら
I'm reading a comic and a kid whos all beaten up and starving is lying down unconscious at a train station

目ぽかっと開けてるようになったらあかんわ

I recently learned the usage of ようになる and came across this in a comic I am slowly reading. I know あかん means like “its no good/hopeless”

What's the point of っと? Is it quotative?

I cant find the meaning of ぽか. What is it mean here?

But then I'm a bit confused why its using the たら conditional structure?


The sentence seems to mean based of context: “It's no good, the kids not going to open his eyes”


This と is part of ぽかっと, which is a variant of ぽかんと or ぽかりと. と by itself is an adverbializing suffix rather than a quotative particle. See: Connection between phenomime じ and adverb じっ‐と?
たら is simply "if". See the translation below.


目ぽかっと開けてるようになったらあかんわ
If one starts keeping their eyes wide open absentmindedly, it's no good.
→ If they can't even close your eyes, (it means) they're hopeless.

